Creating a Angular table with dynamic columns with the count
I need to create table like below in Angular with my API data.
Each product will have multiple station's with the count.
What I need is Each product I need to display in a row also station needs to be part of columns
Below is my API data
[
  {
    "productId": 1,
    "productName": "250 litre",
    "stationCount": {
      "Assembly": 1,
      "Moulding": 0,
      "Polishing": 1,
      "Post Mould Graphic Install": 0,
      "Product Wrapping": 0,
      "Spin Welding": 0,
      "Spin Welding Drainage Outlet": 0,
      "Trimming": 0,
      "Wheel Assembly": 3
    }
  },
  {
    "productId": 2,
    "productName": "300 litre",
    "stationCount": {
      "Assembly": 0,
      "Moulding": 3,
      "Polishing": 0,
      "Post Mould Graphic Install": 1,
      "Product Wrapping": 0,
      "Spin Welding": 0,
      "Spin Welding Drainage Outlet": 1,
      "Trimming": 1,
      "Wheel Assembly": 0
    }
  } 
]



I have achieved using below code
tableDataSource: any[] = [];
displayedColumns: string[] = [];
stationColumns: any[] = [];

if (result.length > 0) {
    this.tableDataSource = result;
    this.stationColumns = Object.keys(this.tableDataSource[0].stationCount); 
    this.displayedColumns = ['Product Name', ...this.stationColumns];              
} 


<table class="table table-bordernone">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns">{{ column }}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let product of tableDataSource">
            <td>{{ product.productName }}</td>
            <td *ngFor="let station of stationColumns">
                {{ product.stationCount[station] }}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

